# Получение фотографии из урла

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте!

Ситуация такова:
Получаю респонс с коментариями из закрытой группы.
В массиве `$json['response'][1]['text']` есть урл на фотку
http://vk.com/photo-624232233_3184631
При переходе "ошибка доступа", метод photos в апи исплользовал

вопрос, как получить через апи чистый url на фотку, сидящей на сервере vk?

Answer (score 1):

У вас должен быть доступ к фотографии, без этого никак.

Узнать все данные о фото можно методом https://vk.com/dev/photos.getById

Comment: Проблема в том, что я вызываю wall.getComments, но мне accesskey не предоставляется, хотя в группе посмотреть эту картинку могу